# Why does doing Django query cause: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django 1.8.2 project.

This project has multiple Django applications.

Application `app_a` has class `MyClassA` as follows:

```
class MyClassA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    @staticmethod
    def my_static_method():
        ret_val = MyClassA.objects.filter()
        return "World"
```

Application `app_b` has class `MyClassB` as follows:

```
class MyClassB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    def my_method(self, arg1=MyClassA.my_static_method()):
        return "Hello"
```

When I run `manage.py test`, it works fine.

However, then I change `MyClassA.my_static_method()` to the following:

```
@staticmethod
def my_static_method():
    ret_val = MyClassA.objects.filter(name=None)
    return "World"
```

When I do that, and then run `manage.py test`, it fails with the following error:

```
  File "my-virtual-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
  django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Why is this happening? How do I fix this?

The only change that I made is adding the filter value `name=None`.

Comment: 1. Do you have `app_a` before `app_b` in `INSTALLED_APPS`? 2. I think the reason why you are seeing the exception raised when you add the `name=None` filter and not otherwise, might be somewhat related to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy. That is, I think that when you just call `filter()` it's possible that your query is not even being evaluated, and so it is hiding your problem. If you add `print(ret_val)` to your empty `filter()` example, you might see the same thing happen.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Adding `print ret_val` with the empty filter doesn't cause the error. Notably this is not a run-time error. It is a compile-time error since `MyClassB.my_method()` is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django you must not run queries at import time. (See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded) for details.)

Because default argument values in Python are evaluated when the function is defined (as opposed to when it is called), your `MyClassB.my_method()` definition is calling `MyClassA.my_static_method()`, which attempts to run a query.

Why did you see an error in one version of your code and not the other? One of them is evaluating the query (i.e. trying to access the database) and one isn't, for whatever reason. It's your responsibility to make sure that nothing you do at import time tries to access the database.

If your goal is for that default argument to be evaluated on each call, the standard idiom in Python is:

```
def my_method(self, arg1=None):
    if arg1 is None:
        arg1 = MyClassA.my_static_method()
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will get an error only if you make a mistake in the manager function. I tried the same and it worked for me. but I got the same error when I made an error in the filter() .like MyClassA.objects.filter(a_field_not_in_the_model=None).

I think you have to re check your original code. check if your model is ok.